# Inflate Exception on using Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to use Google Maps in Android app.I have added google Play Service and created SH1 and API key Using Google API Console.In my android app When i use Fragment in .Xml,i am getting error as Android.view.inflateException.Please help me in solving this.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GOOGLE PLAY SERVICE AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GOOGLE PLAY SERVICE AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try { 
        if (googleMap == null) {
           googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
           findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
        }
     googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

**main.Xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/the_map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="14"
/>
```

**Androidmanifest.xml:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<permission
android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
     <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyBSQwglzqj0xivCRkQ0rhxi6BiKslrbFvA" />
</application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Google Maps v2 and add this in layout

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

for more help [Google Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)